# Any way to get all rows of a table where the foreign key matches the primary key using only models rather than accessing the database directly?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two models: User and Lesson.  Lessons are tied to users through a user_id foreign key in Lessons.  I want to say "give me all lessons for user 8", but the only way I've been able to accomplish that is by going through the DB class

```
$lessons = DB::table('lessons')->where('user_id','=',8)->get();
```

Is there a way to do something like this?

```
$lessons = Lesson::all()->where('user_id','=',8);
```

or (even better)

```
$lessons = User::find(8)->lessons();
```

Just wondering because the latter two ways make more sense.  Just wondering!

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this:

```
$lessons = Lesson::where('user_id', 8)->get(); // '=' is optional
```

Or `user` with lessons:

```
$userWithLessons = User::with('lessons')->find(8);
```

Also `User::find(8)->lessons;` will work but eager loading (`with('lessons')`) is better.

Another way depending on `id` in `users` table:

```
// pass the id in $id
$lessons = Lesson::with('user')->whereHas('user', function($q) use ($id){
    $q->where('id', $id);
})->get();
```

**Update:** You may try this

```
// pass the id in $id
$id = 8; // user id
$lesson71 = Lesson::with('users')->whereHas('users', function($q) use ($id){
    $q->where('id', $id);
})->find(71);
```

Comment: Is there a way to filter this down?  User::with('lessons')->find(8); returns me an array of lessons with the user, but is there a way to say User::with('lessons')->find(8)->find(71); ("return me user 8 with only lesson 71")

Comment: What relationship have you used, do you have a `users` function in `Lesson` model, how it looks like ?