# How to get /user/8/lesson/79 to work without giving user access to all lessons?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have two models: a user model and a lesson model.  Users to lessons is a one to many relationship.  I defined this hasMany relationship in User and Lesson model.

Essentially, I want to constrain the user to their lessons; user 8 shouldn't be able to have access to user 7's lessons.

However, this doesn't work:

```
return User::find($userId)->lessons()->where('id',$id);
```

and I don't want to say

```
return Lessons::find($lessonId)
```

because that means any user can do anything with another user's lessons.

Comment: I think, I've answered your same question you asked, is this different ?

Comment: This is a different question.  I'm trying to filter all the lessons I've got from /user/8/lesson so I am only dealing with one lesson instead.  Essentially, how do I say "/user/8/lesson/79" without giving any user access to all lessons (e.g. Lesson::find($lessonId))

Comment: Your question is not clear, what do you want here ?

Comment: Whenever I go to this route: "/user/8/lesson/79" I want to deal with lesson 79 if and only if the user owns it.

Comment: It depends on the insertion, when you inserting/saving the lesson in the database, make sure you make an association/relation with that user only.

Comment: I'm only trying to show the record... Maybe it'll help if I show you the route?

Route::get('/user/{uid}/lesson/{lid}', 'LessonController@show');

Comment: Actually `user::with('lessons')->find(8)` will return all the lessons that user `8` owns and you should save the lesson with the relationship when creating it.

Comment: What you tried seems to imply that a user has many lessons, which you indicated was not true in the answer below. How is a user related to a lesson? Does a user have a lesson, or does a user only have access to a lesson? Is there an access table that controls this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any way to get all rows of a table where the foreign key matches the primary key using only models rather than accessing the database directly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23302768/any-way-to-get-all-rows-of-a-table-where-the-foreign-key-matches-the-primary-key)

Comment: Well, the user creates their own custom lessons.  But that user may, after creating a lesson, want to see/edit/delete that custom lesson.  I'm trying to see if there is a way to say this using Eloquent ORM, and not the DB class?

Comment: Did you check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23302768/any-way-to-get-all-rows-of-a-table-where-the-foreign-key-matches-the-primary-key/23302982#23302982) ?

Comment: Checked but it doesn't work.  
    
    $lesson = User::with('lessons')->find($id);

returns a blank screen (though, no errors).

Wait wait wait... Okay, so how do I further filter once I have all lessons for user 8?  What is I want all lessons from user 8 and from those lessons I want to be able to say "get me lesson 79".

E.g. is there a way to say User::with('lessons')->find(8)->find(79)?

Comment: I was looking for authentication filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function show($userId, $lessonId)
{
    $lesson = Lesson::find($lessonId);
    if($lesson->user_id == $userId)
    {
        return $lesson;
    } else {
        return "You don't have access!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is a [filter](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters)

```
Route::filter('userlessons', function($route, $request)
{
    // there's probably a better way to get the values from the request,
    // but I couldn't find it
    //
    $uid = $request->segment(2);
    $lid = $request->segment(4);

    // check user ID & lesson values - not sure how you want to test this;
    // I just made something up here
    //
    if(!User::find($uid)->lessons->contains($lid))
        throw new NotAuthorizedException("You can't do that!");
});



Route::get("user/{uid}/lesson/{lid}", array("before"=>"userlessons", function($uid, $lid){

    return "That user can access that lesson!";

}));
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the lessons related to a given user use dynamic property:

```
$user = User::find($userId);
$lessons = $user->lessons
```

be sure in your User model to have the hasMany relationship

```
public function lessons(){

    return $this->hasMany('lesson');
}
```

Comment: which lesson do you want? eloquent is an ORM it just make it easier to deal with database. if you want to retrieve data from your database, specify what are the criteria of your query

Comment: I'm giving the user id and the lesson id in the route ("/user/8/lesson/79" means "give me lesson with id of 79 from user 8").  Right now, I'm attempting to show lesson 79 if and only if it's owned by user 8.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filters as suggested by Kryten or simply do what you tried with a little fix:

```
try {
  $user->lessons()->findOrFail($id);
}
catch (ModelNotFoundException $e)
{
  // give feedback that lesson was not found or does not belong to this user
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this? Assuming lesson model has `user_id` property

```
 Route::get('user/{uid}/lessons/{lid}', function($uid, $lid) {
      $lesson = Lesson::whereUserId($uid)->find($lid);

      if(is_null($lesson))
      {
         return Redirect::to('/error-page');
      }

      // Do stuff with $lesson, i.e generate view here.
      return View::make('lesson', compact('lesson'));

 });
```